# How to get what the user is typing and display it on a label in swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I'm making a form in Swift, and want to get what the user is typing to display it on the screen as they type.

I've tried to use the following code to get what the user is typing as they type but it is not showing:

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool 
[enter image description here][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xfdJ.png
```

Comment: Show your relevant code and clearly explain what is and isn’t doing.

Answer (score 0):

UITextView will show what the user is typing, but if you need the actual text as the user is typing, the method you used is fine, you just need to perform the replacement since the method you used is asking for permission to change the current text depending on the new input, so you get the final text by:

```
if let text = textField.text, let range = Range(range, in: text) {
   let newText = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
   print(newText) // <-- String of the new text, do what you want with it
}
```